# Сервер отправляет объект не null, а клиент принимает null

Tags: c#, wcf

C сервера на клиент посылается задача, но на клиент она приходит как null. Первые несколько задач клиент принимает и они не null, они нормально передаются. Но в какой то момент раз и null. Вот ссылка на репозиторий с фул проектом: https://github.com/DarkByte2015/CoursedWork_v5. Буду очень признателен если кто то сможет помочь. Минимально воспроизводимый пример:

```
namespace CWServer.ViewModels
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private JobService ServiceInstance;
        private ServiceHost ServiceHost;
        private Queue<ClientJob> Jobs = new Queue<ClientJob>();
        private int JobCount;
        private List<double> Results = new List<double>();
        public ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel> Clients { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ClientViewModel>();

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            StartServer();
            SolveAsync();
        }

        private void StartServer()
        {
            ServiceInstance = new JobService();
            ServiceInstance.ClientConnected += ClientConnected;
            ServiceInstance.ClientDisconnected += ClientDisconnected;
            ServiceInstance.ClientCalculated += ClientCalculated;
            ServiceHost = new ServiceHost(ServiceInstance);
            ServiceHost.Open();
        }

        private void StopServer()
        {
            Clients.AsParallel().ForAll(c => c.DisconnectAsync());            
            ServiceHost.Close();
            Dispatch(() => Clients.Clear());
        }

        private async void SolveAsync() => await Task.Run(() => Solve());

        private void Solve()
        {
            foreach (var job in ClientJob.Distribute())
                Jobs.Enqueue(job);

            JobCount = Jobs.Count;
            Clients.AsParallel().ForAll(c => TryGiveJob(c));

            while (LockingCall.Invoke(() => Results.Count != JobCount, JobCount)) ;

            Results.Clear();
        }

        private void ClientConnected(object sender, ClientChangeStateEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new ClientViewModel(e.Callback);
            client.ClientAborted += ClientAborted;
            Dispatch(() => Clients.Add(client));
            TryGiveJob(client);
        }

        private void ClientDisconnected(object sender, ClientChangeStateEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = Clients.First(c => c.Callback == e.Callback);
            RemoveClient(client);
        }

        private void ClientAborted(object sender, ClientAbortedEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = sender as ClientViewModel;
            RemoveClient(client);
        }

        private void ClientCalculated(object sender, ClientCalculatedEventArgs e)
        {
            var client = Clients.First(c => c.Callback == e.Callback);
            client.EndCalculationAsync();
            LockingCall.Invoke(() => Results.Add(1.0), sender);
            TryGiveJob(client);
        }

        private bool TryGiveJob(ClientViewModel client)
        {
            if (LockingCall.Invoke(() => Jobs.Count > 0, client))
            {
                if (LockingCall.Invoke(() => Jobs.Peek() == null, client))
                    Debugger.Launch();

                var job = LockingCall.Invoke(() => Jobs.Dequeue(), client);
                client.BeginCalculationAsync(job);
                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }

        private void RemoveClient(ClientViewModel client)
        {
            if (client.IsCalculating)
                LockingCall.Invoke(() => Jobs.Enqueue(client.Job), JobCount);

            Dispatch(() => Clients.Remove(client));
        }

        private void Dispatch(Action action) => Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}

namespace CWServer.ViewModels
{
    public class ClientViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public event EventHandler<ClientAbortedEventArgs> ClientAborted;
        public IClientCallback Callback { get; }
        public ClientJob Job { get; private set; }
        public bool IsCalculating { get { return Job != null; } }

        public ClientViewModel(IClientCallback callback)
        {
            Callback = callback;
        }

        public async void DisconnectAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => Callback.OnServerIsStopped());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        public async void BeginCalculationAsync(ClientJob job)
        {
            if (job == null)
                Debug.WriteLine("BeginCalculationAsync: job == null");

            Job = job;

            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => Callback.OnGiveJob(Job));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                var args = new ClientAbortedEventArgs(e, Job);
                ClientAborted?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }

        public async void EndCalculationAsync() => await Task.Run((Action)EndCalculation);

        private void EndCalculation()
        {
            Job = null;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
    public class ClientJob
    {
        public static ClientJob[] Distribute() => Enumerable.Repeat<ClientJob>(null, 20000).Select(j => new ClientJob()).ToArray();
    }

namespace CWServer.ServiceContracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IClientCallback
    {
        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void OnGiveJob(ClientJob job);

        [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
        void OnServerIsStopped();
    }
}

namespace CWServer.ServiceContracts
{
    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IClientCallback))]
    public interface IJobService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void Connect();

        [OperationContract]
        void SetResult(ClientJob job);

        [OperationContract]
        void Disconnect();
    }
}

namespace CWServer.ServiceContracts
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Reentrant, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class JobService : IJobService
    {
        public event EventHandler<ClientChangeStateEventArgs> ClientConnected;

        public event EventHandler<ClientChangeStateEventArgs> ClientDisconnected;

        public event EventHandler<ClientCalculatedEventArgs> ClientCalculated;

        void IJobService.Connect()
        {
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();
            var address = GetClientAddress();
            var args = new ClientChangeStateEventArgs(callback, address);
            ClientConnected?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        void IJobService.Disconnect()
        {
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();
            var address = GetClientAddress();
            var args = new ClientChangeStateEventArgs(callback, address);
            ClientDisconnected?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        void IJobService.SetResult(ClientJob job)
        {
            var callback = OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>();
            var args = new ClientCalculatedEventArgs(callback, job);
            ClientCalculated?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        private string GetClientAddress()
        {
            var context = OperationContext.Current;
            var prop = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
            var endpoint = prop[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name] as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;
            return endpoint.Address;
        }
    }
}

namespace CWClient
{
    class Program : IJobServiceCallback
    {
        private JobServiceClient client;

        public async void OnGiveJob(ClientJob job)
        {
            Debug.Assert(job != null);
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            await client.SetResultAsync(job);
        }

        public void OnServerIsStopped()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Stopped.");
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var program = new Program();
            var context = new InstanceContext(program);
            program.client = new JobServiceClient(context); // строку подключения оставим в конфиг-файле 
            program.client.Connect();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас гонка между `BeginCalculationAsync` и `EndCalculation`. Дело в том, что в методе `ClientCalculated` вы сначала вызываете второй метод, потом - первый. Но второй метод вызывается асинхронно и работает параллельно с первым!

Вот и получается, что пока `BeginCalculationAsync` выполняется - свойство `Job` тихонько становится `null` в методе `EndCalculation`!

Зачем вы вообще сделали метод `EndCalculation` асинхронным? В нем нет ничего, что могло бы потребовать нового потока. Уберите метод `EndCalculationAsync`, сделайте `EndCalculation` открытым - и все заработает так, как планировалось.

---

PS вы слишком часто используете `Task.Run`, а отсюда идут проблемы, которые вы пытаетесь закрыть при помощи `Dispatcher` и `LockingCall`. Предлагаю вам альтернативный вариант: сервер можно написать вообще без использования потоков!

1. Сделайте методы обратного вызова в интерфейсе `IClientCallback` возвращающими `Task` - тогда вам не понадобится создавать для них отдельный поток.
2. Добавьте настройку [`UseSynchronisationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.usesynchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) в атрибут `ServiceBehavior` - тогда WCF будет вызывать методы вашего сервиса уже в потоке UI.
3. Выкиньте из кода **вообще все** вызовы `LockingCall`, `Dispatch`, `Task.Run` и `AsParallel`- используйте только оператор `await`. Соответственно, большинство методов надо будет переделать на асинхронные (но *не на async void* - они должны быть `async Task`!). Тогда ваша программа перестанет подкидывать вам сюрпризы, с которыми вы потом несколько дней разбираетесь.

Вероятно, у вас возникнет затруднение с методом `Solve`, а именно с ожиданием когда все задачи закончатся.

Проще всего (для вас) использовать асинхронное активное ожидание:

```
while (Results.Count != JobCount)
  await Task.Delay(100);
```

Задержки в 100 миллисекунд достаточно чтобы, с одной стороны, программа не тормозила из-за цикла - а с другой стороны, пользователь ее не заметил.

Более красивого решения можно достичь при использовании `TaskCompletionSource` для ожидания события:

```
// в методе Solve
doneEvent = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
await doneEvent.Task;

// ...

// в методе ClientCalculated
if (Results.Count == JobCount)
  doneEvent.SetResult(null);
```